# getting the path of a file from its grandparent folder

Tags: php, relative-path

I have a php file which has the following path

```
Shubhmangalam/admin/welcome_image_edition/delete_image.php
```

and an image file with the following path

```
Shubhmangalam/welcome_images/image_1.jpg
```

I want to delete the image_1.jpg file which I know can be done by using unlink() method..
but the prob is that the parent folder of the `.php`  file and `.jpg` file is different, and so is their level of file-system...and I cant find the proper way to get the path to delete the image_1.jpg file.

Now the code on the delete_image.php is accordingly

```
<?php
$image=$_REQUEST['image'];
if(unlink("./../welcome_images/".$image))
   echo "Successfully Deleted";
else 
   echo "Wrong";
?>
```

Now the above is server-scripting code, I want to delete the image by getting appropriate path.. I dont want the actual path, but the path from the project folder that is `Shubhmangalam`

thanks in advance

Comment: ok, i got my answer, i need to find the parent of grand-parent of the file delete_image.php

so i used the code

    "../../welcome_images/".$image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be VERY careful with this type of code. You're not filtering the $_REQUEST value AT ALL, which allows a malicious user to specify ANY file on your server, e.g:

```
http://example.com/delete_image.php?image=../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd
```

You can fix your pathing problem by using an absolute path:

```
unlink('/path/leading/to/your/welcome_images/' . $image);
```

which relives you of the burden of having to figure out the appropriate relative path.

Comment: ok, i got my answer, i need to find the parent of grand-parent of the file delete_image.php

so i used the code

    "../../welcome_images/".$image

Answer (score 2):

```
 Shubhmangalam/admin/welcome_image_edition/delete_image.php
```

That is:

```
 __FILE__
```

and an image file with the follwing path

```
 Shubhmangalam/welcome_images/image_1.jpg
```

That is:

```
 dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/welcome_images/image_1.jp';
```

in the first file. Use the [magic constants `__FILE__` and `__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for your own good, e.g.:

```
if (unlink(__DIR__."/../../welcome_images/".$image))
{
    ...
```